# Print all combination of a string using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, combinations

I have an assignment to write code that printing all combinations of N char.  For example, if the input is 3, the expected output must be "*aaa aab aac aba ... ccc*". But my code looping over and over again. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef MAX
#define MAX 5
#endif

void comb(char kar[], int size, int index) {
    // string = aaa
    // lim = 'd'
    char lim = 'a' + size;
    while (index != -1) {

        if (kar[size-1] != lim) { // != c
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                printf("%s ", kar);
                kar[size-1]+=1;
            }
            return comb(kar, size, index);

        } else {

            while (kar[index-1] == lim && index != -1) {
                kar[index-1]='a';
                index--;
            }
            kar[index-1] += 1;

            return comb(kar, size, size);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n;
    char kar[MAX];

    printf("Input N char : ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        kar[j] = 'a';
    }

    comb(kar, n, n);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a little bit confused and I have no idea where is the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: OT: Hint: dont write `97` but `'a'`. It's mor ereadable and clearly shows your intention.

Comment: Slightly OT: zero initialize the kar array like this: `char kar[MAX] = { 0 };`, otherwise you will most likely print garbage.

Comment: You only ever pass `n`, `index`, and `size` as the `index` argument, and you never assign to it within `comb`, so it's hard to see how `index != -1` could ever become false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I changed some elements in the `comb()` and added the `pow()` function to define the recursion limit.

```
int comb(char kar[], int size, int index, int limit) {

    char lim = 97 + size;
    int limit_value = pow(size,size);
    if(limit == limit_value){
        return 1;

    } else {

        if (index < size-1) {
            printf("%s ", kar);
            kar[size-1]+=1;
            return comb(kar, size, index+1, limit+1);

        } else {
            int cek = index;
            printf("%s ", kar);
            while (kar[cek] == lim-1 ) {
                kar[cek]=97;
                cek-=1;
            }
            kar[cek] += 1;

            return comb(kar, size, 0, limit+1);
        }
    }
}
```